# How to solve gurobipy.GurobiError: Objective Q not PSD? (with simple examples)

Tags: python, gurobi, quadratic

I'm trying to solve some quadratic linear programming problems using gurobi and python, but with error like

gurobipy.GurobiError: Objective Q not PSD (diagonal adjustment of 1.0e+00 would be required)

I have trouble with this error.

So I tried some simple example like..

Minimize x1 * x2

Subject to

x1 <= 30 and x1 >= 20

x2 <= 30 and x2 >= 20

and

Maximize x1 * x2

Subject to

x1 <= 30 and x1 >= 20

x2 <= 30 and x2 >= 20

Gurobi can solve the former but not latter.

```py
    from gurobipy import *

    m = Model()

    #variables
    x1 = m.addVar(vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, lb=20, ub=30, name="x1")
    x2 = m.addVar(vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, lb=20, ub=30, name="x2")

    m.update()

    m.setObjective(x1 * x2, GRB.MINIMIZE)  # or GRB.MAXIMIZE

    m.update()

    m.optimize()
```

I changed MINIMIZE to MAXIMIZE, hoping to get optimal objective 900, but gurobi cannot handle this problem. Here's my result.

MINIMIZE case

```
Optimize a model with 0 rows, 2 columns and 0 nonzeros
Model has 1 quadratic objective term
Coefficient statistics:
  Matrix range     [0e+00, 0e+00]
  Objective range  [0e+00, 0e+00]
  QObjective range [2e+00, 2e+00]
  Bounds range     [2e+01, 3e+01]
  RHS range        [0e+00, 0e+00]
Presolve removed 0 rows and 2 columns
Presolve time: 0.00s
Presolve: All rows and columns removed
Barrier solved model in 0 iterations and 0.00 seconds
Optimal objective 4.00000000e+02
```

MAXIMIZE case

```
Optimize a model with 0 rows, 2 columns and 0 nonzeros
Model has 1 quadratic objective term
Coefficient statistics:
  Matrix range     [0e+00, 0e+00]
  Objective range  [0e+00, 0e+00]
  QObjective range [2e+00, 2e+00]
  Bounds range     [2e+01, 3e+01]
  RHS range        [0e+00, 0e+00]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\encl1\.conda\envs\kicarus\lib\site-                packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3296, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-98-df9d183baafd>", line 16, in <module>
    m.optimize()
  File "model.pxi", line 727, in gurobipy.Model.optimize     (../../src/python/gurobipy.c:57790)
gurobipy.GurobiError: Objective Q not PSD (diagonal adjustment of 1.0e+00     would be required)
```

Please explain why MAXIMIZE isn't working though MINIMIZE is working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent Gurobi from converting a Max into a Min prob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24588849/how-to-prevent-gurobi-from-converting-a-max-into-a-min-prob)